# Unable to SSH into ec2 from MacOSx

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have been trying to connect to my ec2 instance which was working a few hours ago. After I terminated my bash terminal abruptly, it refuses to work now. I'm getting a constant `ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out` error.

It worked on my friend's ubuntu system but fails to work even on my ubuntu. 
I've allowed all the inbound and outbound routes too.

Have also used the correct command, made my .pem key private and all. Still doesn't work. What do I do

Comment: Restart your Mac. Also make sure that host exists (copy public IP of EC2)

Comment: I'm a newbie. What do you mean by copy public IP of EC2 ?

Comment: Ok. Turns out my university wifi blocks port 22. I tried ping and all of them timed out. So, now I am trying it on a personal hotspot and its working

Comment: So delete your question as it does not solve any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the instance is turned on or its ip changed. Each ec2 instance has a private IP and a public IP, we should use the public IP of the ec2 to ssh to it. Find the public IP  in the aws console.

Comment: I'm using the publicIPv4 domain only. Its timing out every single time

Comment: Did you see if the instance is actually running?

Comment: Yeah Its running on the ec2 console. I also tried a reboot. Doesnt work. The same thing works in my friend's ubuntu system. He's on a different network though

Comment: Yeah, there are such pointers to your solution, the instance may be connectable only from certain networks or the port 22 may be open to certain networks only.

Comment: Ok. Turns out my university wifi blocks port 22. I tried ping and all of them timed out. So, now I am trying it on a personal hotspot and its working. Thanks for you insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify your attached EC2 security group, and check if the port ssh is open from your network. (with nmap for example).

In the security group validates that the source port is wide open or just open from your current public ip. (the last is more secure / recommended)